# Wordpress Different Home page for loged in and logged out users

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to set different home pages for logged in users

this working somethimes and somethimes not

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
$page = get_page_by_path( '/front-page');
update_option( 'page_on_front', $page->ID );
update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
else {
$page = get_page_by_path( '' );
update_option( 'page_on_front', $page->ID );
update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the options is not going to be reliable. Using [the `template_redirect` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) with [`wp_safe_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/) will be more reliable.

Untested:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', static function () {
    if ( ! is_front_page() ) {
        return;
    }

    nocache_headers();

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! wp_safe_redirect( 'front-page' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    exit;
} );
```